# Complex Javascript, how to concatenate letters to compose a word in a right way, while resizing window

Tags: javascript

My problem is that every letter is in inside a span and is managed as a unit,
so while resizing the window words may be truncate in a wrong way,
so letters that composite a word may be in different lines.

How can I solve?

I know that script should be more complex than this one, but I don't know how to do this trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*
   * Main variables
   */
  var content = [{
    title: "Hi! Mate.",
    desc: "Welcome to my alphabet soup demo!"
  }, {
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  }, {
    title: "dolor sit amet",
    desc: "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  }, {
    title: "Grouping example",
    desc: [
      ["<u>Grouped text</u>"], " separate text".split("")
    ]
  }];
  var currentPage = 0;
  //generate content
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    //split content letters to array
    for (var obj in content[i]) {
      //if string
      if (typeof content[i][obj] === "string") {
        content[i][obj] = content[i][obj].split("");
        continue;
      }
      //if array (grouped text)
      else if (typeof content[i][obj] === "object") {
        var toPush = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < content[i][obj].length; j++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < content[i][obj][j].length; k++) {
            toPush.push(content[i][obj][j][k]);
          }
        }
        content[i][obj] = toPush;
      }
    }
    //set text to 
    $("#segments").append("<div class=\"letters-wrap mutable\"><div class=\"soup-title\"></div><div class=\"soup-desc\"></div></div>");
    setText();
    //clone to data
    $("#segments").append("<div class=\"letters-wrap position-data\"><div class=\"soup-title\"></div><div class=\"soup-desc\"></div></div>");
    setText();
  }
  //initial arrangement
  arrangeCurrentPage();
  scrambleOthers();
  /*
   * Event handlers
   */
  $(window).resize(function() {
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
  });
  $("#soup-prev").hide();
  $("#soup-prev").click(function() {
    $("#soup-next").show();
    currentPage--;
    if (currentPage === 0) {
      $("#soup-prev").hide();
    }
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
  });
  $("#soup-next").click(function() {
    $("#soup-prev").show();
    currentPage++;
    if (currentPage === content.length - 1) {
      $("#soup-next").hide();
    }
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
  });
  /*
   * Functions
   */
  function arrangeCurrentPage() {
    for (var i = 0; i < content[currentPage].title.length; i++) {
      $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).css({
        left: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).offset().left + "px",
        top: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).offset().top + "px",
        color: "#111",
        zIndex: 9001
      });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < content[currentPage].desc.length; i++) {
      $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).css({
        left: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).offset().left + "px",
        top: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).offset().top + "px",
        color: "#111",
        zIndex: 9001
      });
    }
  }

  function setText() {
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < content[i].title.length; j++) {
      $(".soup-title").last().append("<span class=\"letter\">" + content[i].title[j] + "</span>");
    }
    for (j = 0; j < content[i].desc.length; j++) {
      $(".soup-desc").last().append("<span class=\"letter\">" + content[i].desc[j] + "</span>");
    }
  }

  function scrambleOthers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      //don't scramble currentPage
      if (currentPage === i)
        continue;
      var parts = [
        ["title", ".soup-title"],
        ["desc", ".soup-desc"]
      ];
      //apply to .title h1s and .desc ps
      for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < content[i][parts[j][0]].length; k++) {
          //define random position on screen
          var randLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());
          var randTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());
          //defining boundaries
          var offset = $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).offset();
          var bounds = {
            left: offset.left,
            top: offset.top,
            right: $(window).width() - offset.left,
            bottom: $(window).height() - offset.top
          };
          var middleX = bounds.left + $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).width() / 2;
          var middleY = bounds.top + $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).height() / 2;
          //finally, apply all the scrambles
          $(".mutable:eq(" + i + ") > " + parts[j][1] + " > .letter").eq(k).css({
            left: randLeft,
            top: randTop,
            color: "#DDD",
            zIndex: "initial"
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #111111;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#soup-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 32px;
  z-index: 9002;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.soup-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.soup-desc {
  font-size: 16px;
}

#soup-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 480px;
  position: relative;
}

.letters-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable .letter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 2s, top 2s, color 2s;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable .letter.active {
  color: #111111;
  z-index: 9001;
}

.letters-wrap.position-data {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /*opacity: 0.1;
   */
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.segment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.letter {
  /*display: inline-block;
   */
  white-space: pre;
}

button {
  z-index: 9001;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="soup-container">
  <div id="segments"></div>
  <div id="soup-nav">
    <span id="soup-prev"><i class="lni-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"><-</i></span>
    <span id="soup-next"><i class="lni-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">-></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific example of how to create the problem? Just testing between the small snippet window and the full window shows no issues - the letters re-arrange themselves seemingly correctly.

Comment: Have to run locally. It's not working in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using JavaScript for layout manipulation, you could calculate the width of the container and programmatically determine when to break the line. Below is my attempt at it, I've added the function `arrangeLetters()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content = [{
    title: "Hi! Mate.",
    desc: "Welcome to my alphabet soup demo!"
  }, {
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  }, {
    title: "dolor sit amet",
    desc: "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  }, {
    title: "Grouping example",
    desc: [
      ["<u>Grouped text</u>"], " separate text".split("")
    ]
  }];
  var currentPage = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    for (var obj in content[i]) {
      if (typeof content[i][obj] === "string") {
        content[i][obj] = content[i][obj].split("");
        continue;
      } else if (typeof content[i][obj] === "object") {
        var toPush = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < content[i][obj].length; j++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < content[i][obj][j].length; k++) {
            toPush.push(content[i][obj][j][k]);
          }
        }
        content[i][obj] = toPush;
      }
    }
    $("#segments").append("<div class=\"letters-wrap mutable\"><div class=\"soup-title\"></div><div class=\"soup-desc\"></div></div>");
    setText();
    //clone to data
    $("#segments").append("<div class=\"letters-wrap position-data\"><div class=\"soup-title\"></div><div class=\"soup-desc\"></div></div>");
    setText();
  }
  arrangeCurrentPage();
  scrambleOthers();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
  });
  $("#soup-prev").hide();
  $("#soup-prev").click(function() {
    $("#soup-next").show();
    currentPage--;
    if (currentPage === 0) {
      $("#soup-prev").hide();
    }
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
    arrangeLetters();
  });
  $("#soup-next").click(function() {
    $("#soup-prev").show();
    currentPage++;
    if (currentPage === content.length - 1) {
      $("#soup-next").hide();
    }
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
    arrangeLetters();
  });

  function arrangeCurrentPage() {
    for (var i = 0; i < content[currentPage].title.length; i++) {
      $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).css({
        left: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).offset().left + "px",
        top: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).offset().top + "px",
        color: "#111",
        zIndex: 9001
      });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < content[currentPage].desc.length; i++) {
      $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).css({
        left: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).offset().left + "px",
        top: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).offset().top + "px",
        color: "#111",
        zIndex: 9001
      });
    }
  }

  function setText() {
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < content[i].title.length; j++) {
      $(".soup-title").last().append("<span class=\"letter\">" + content[i].title[j] + "</span>");
    }
    for (j = 0; j < content[i].desc.length; j++) {
      $(".soup-desc").last().append("<span class=\"letter\">" + content[i].desc[j] + "</span>");
    }
  }

  function scrambleOthers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      if (currentPage === i)
        continue;
      var parts = [
        ["title", ".soup-title"],
        ["desc", ".soup-desc"]
      ];
      for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < content[i][parts[j][0]].length; k++) {
          var randLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());
          var randTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());
          var offset = $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).offset();
          var bounds = {
            left: offset.left,
            top: offset.top,
            right: $(window).width() - offset.left,
            bottom: $(window).height() - offset.top
          };
          var middleX = bounds.left + $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).width() / 2;
          var middleY = bounds.top + $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).height() / 2;
          $(".mutable:eq(" + i + ") > " + parts[j][1] + " > .letter").eq(k).css({
            left: randLeft,
            top: randTop,
            color: "#DDD",
            zIndex: "initial"
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function arrangeLetters() {
    let container = $("#soup-container");
    let containerWidth = container.width();
    let containerCenter = container.offset().left + containerWidth / 2;
    let titleTop = $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ")").offset().top;
    let titleHeight = arrangeSection("title", titleTop);

    let descriptionTop = titleTop + titleHeight + 20;
    arrangeSection("desc", descriptionTop);

    function arrangeSection(section, currentTop) {
      let maxLineHeight = 0;
      let sectionHeight = 0;
      let currentLineWidth = 0;
      let lineStartIndex = 0;

      $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-" + section + " > .letter").each(function(index) {
        let letterWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);
        let letterHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
        maxLineHeight = Math.max(maxLineHeight, letterHeight);

        if (currentLineWidth + letterWidth > containerWidth) {

          centerLine(lineStartIndex, index - 1, currentLineWidth, currentTop, section);
          currentTop += maxLineHeight;
          sectionHeight += maxLineHeight;
          currentLineWidth = 0;
          lineStartIndex = index;
          maxLineHeight = letterHeight;
        }

        currentLineWidth += letterWidth;
      });

      centerLine(lineStartIndex, $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-" + section + " > .letter").length - 1, currentLineWidth, currentTop, section);
      sectionHeight += maxLineHeight;

      return sectionHeight;
    }

    function centerLine(startIndex, endIndex, lineWidth, currentTop, section) {
      let currentLeft = containerCenter - lineWidth / 2;
      $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-" + section + " > .letter").slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1).each(function() {
        $(this).css({
          top: currentTop + "px",
          left: currentLeft + "px"
        });
        currentLeft += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      });
    }
  }
  arrangeLetters();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #111111;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#soup-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 32px;
  z-index: 9002;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.soup-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.soup-desc {
  font-size: 16px;
}

#soup-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 480px;
  position: relative;
}

.letters-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable .letter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 2s, top 2s, color 2s;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable .letter.active {
  color: #111111;
  z-index: 9001;
}

.letters-wrap.position-data {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.segment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.letter {
  white-space: pre;
}

button {
  z-index: 9001;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="soup-container">
  <div id="segments"></div>
  <div id="soup-nav">
    <span id="soup-prev"><i class="lni-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true">&lt;&#8722;</i></span>
    <span id="soup-next"><i class="lni-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">&#8722;&gt;</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it should be better moving all spans containing single letters inside an other div class "word" and then displaying all words in the container using flex. Could be fine? I don't know how to do that in javascript

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to add line breaks. CMIIW.

Add these 3 lines to `.position-data`:

```css
width: 100%;
max-width: 100vw;
word-break: break-all;
```

---

Preview:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*
   * Main variables
   */
  var content = [{
    title: "Hi! Mate.",
    desc: "Welcome to my alphabet soup demo!"
  }, {
    title: "Lorem ipsum",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  }, {
    title: "dolor sit amet",
    desc: "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  }, {
    title: "Grouping example",
    desc: [
      ["<u>Grouped text</u>"], " separate text".split("")
    ]
  }];
  var currentPage = 0;
  //generate content
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    //split content letters to array
    for (var obj in content[i]) {
      //if string
      if (typeof content[i][obj] === "string") {
        content[i][obj] = content[i][obj].split("");
        continue;
      }
      //if array (grouped text)
      else if (typeof content[i][obj] === "object") {
        var toPush = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < content[i][obj].length; j++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < content[i][obj][j].length; k++) {
            toPush.push(content[i][obj][j][k]);
          }
        }
        content[i][obj] = toPush;
      }
    }
    //set text to 
    $("#segments").append("<div class=\"letters-wrap mutable\"><div class=\"soup-title\"></div><div class=\"soup-desc\"></div></div>");
    setText();
    //clone to data
    $("#segments").append("<div class=\"letters-wrap position-data\"><div class=\"soup-title\"></div><div class=\"soup-desc\"></div></div>");
    setText();
  }
  //initial arrangement
  arrangeCurrentPage();
  scrambleOthers();
  /*
   * Event handlers
   */
  $(window).resize(function() {
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
  });
  $("#soup-prev").hide();
  $("#soup-prev").click(function() {
    $("#soup-next").show();
    currentPage--;
    if (currentPage === 0) {
      $("#soup-prev").hide();
    }
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
  });
  $("#soup-next").click(function() {
    $("#soup-prev").show();
    currentPage++;
    if (currentPage === content.length - 1) {
      $("#soup-next").hide();
    }
    arrangeCurrentPage();
    scrambleOthers();
  });
  /*
   * Functions
   */
  function arrangeCurrentPage() {
    for (var i = 0; i < content[currentPage].title.length; i++) {
      $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).css({
        left: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).offset().left + "px",
        top: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-title > .letter").eq(i).offset().top + "px",
        color: "#111",
        zIndex: 9001
      });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < content[currentPage].desc.length; i++) {
      $(".mutable:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).css({
        left: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).offset().left + "px",
        top: $(".position-data:eq(" + currentPage + ") > .soup-desc > .letter").eq(i).offset().top + "px",
        color: "#111",
        zIndex: 9001
      });
    }
  }

  function setText() {
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < content[i].title.length; j++) {
      $(".soup-title").last().append("<span class=\"letter\">" + content[i].title[j] + "</span>");
    }
    for (j = 0; j < content[i].desc.length; j++) {
      $(".soup-desc").last().append("<span class=\"letter\">" + content[i].desc[j] + "</span>");
    }
  }

  function scrambleOthers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      //don't scramble currentPage
      if (currentPage === i)
        continue;
      var parts = [
        ["title", ".soup-title"],
        ["desc", ".soup-desc"]
      ];
      //apply to .title h1s and .desc ps
      for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < content[i][parts[j][0]].length; k++) {
          //define random position on screen
          var randLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());
          var randTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());
          //defining boundaries
          var offset = $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).offset();
          var bounds = {
            left: offset.left,
            top: offset.top,
            right: $(window).width() - offset.left,
            bottom: $(window).height() - offset.top
          };
          var middleX = bounds.left + $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).width() / 2;
          var middleY = bounds.top + $(".position-data").eq(currentPage).height() / 2;
          //finally, apply all the scrambles
          $(".mutable:eq(" + i + ") > " + parts[j][1] + " > .letter").eq(k).css({
            left: randLeft,
            top: randTop,
            color: "#DDD",
            zIndex: "initial"
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #111111;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#soup-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 32px;
  z-index: 9002;
  font-size: 64px;
}

.soup-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.soup-desc {
  font-size: 16px;
}

#soup-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 480px;
  position: relative;
}

.letters-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable .letter {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 2s, top 2s, color 2s;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

.letters-wrap.mutable .letter.active {
  color: #111111;
  z-index: 9001;
}

.letters-wrap.position-data {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /*opacity: 0.1;
   */
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.segment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.letter {
  /*display: inline-block;
   */
  white-space: pre;
}

button {
  z-index: 9001;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="soup-container">
  <div id="segments"></div>
  <div id="soup-nav">
    <span id="soup-prev"><i class="lni-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"><-</i></span>
    <span id="soup-next"><i class="lni-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">-></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, cause they're single letters inside span